# Convert all function to normal function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I want to understand N-queens problem from EPI.
In this problem I want to write it without all function for understanding it clearly.
How can write the same functionalities for this problem without "all"?

```
for col in range(n):
    # Test if a newly placed queen will conflict any earlier queens
    # placed before.

    if all( abs(c - col) not in (0, row - i) for i, c in enumerate(col_placement[:row])):
        col_placement[row] = col
        solve_n_queens(row + 1)
```

P.S You can get full code from here(https://github.com/adnanaziz/EPIJudge/blob/master/epi_judge_python_solutions/n_queens.py)

Comment: You know what `all` does and/or [where to find what it does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)?

Comment: `all` is not very hard to understand, I think what you might be confused about is the argument inside. Google list comprehensions. (technically it's a generator expression not a list comprehension, but that's not important)

Comment: @usr2564301 I know what **all**, **any** do thank you for your reference.But I can't convert it normal loop without **all** keyword.

Comment: @AlexHall Yes you are correct I think list comprehension is written inside **[]** but it is not.Can you give more detailed explanation how can I convert it normal loop which is when condition meet till the end I call the second part of the code
 **col_placement[row] = col
    solve_n_queens(row + 1) **

Comment: If you can understand list comprehensions then it should be straightfoward to extract a manual loop from there that uses `append`, and the docs show what `all` is equivalent to, so it's not clear what you're confused about.